# Add or insert conditions inside a loop

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php script the loops between two dates.

```
$begin = new DateTime("2018-06-01");  
$end   = new DateTime("2018-06-30");  

for($i = $begin; $i <= $end; $i->modify('+1 day')){  
echo $i->format("Y-m-d");  
}
```

and then i have a mysql data result (5 rows) that contains the date in FRIDAYS.
2018-06-01   - friday
2018-06-08   - friday
2018-06-15   - friday
2018-06-22   - friday
2018-06-29   - friday

how can i integrate this to the for loop so that if friday date matches i can echo something.

i have to do foreach loop inside the for loop, but the problem is that it duplicates which is actually the number of row returned on my mysql data result that contain friday date.

```
for($i = $begin; $i <= $end; $i->modify('+1 day')){  
  foreach($result as $row){  
    if($i->format("Y-m-d")!=$row['rest_day']){  echo $i->format("Y-m-d"); }  
     else{ echo 'Rest Day';}         
  }  
} 

The display here is that for each day it is duplicated 5 times, i think it is because of the number of fridays which is 5, this is actually the number of rows returned from the mysql data result.
```

The FRIDAYS is just an example, it may change from time to time, so basically it is dynamic.
what could be the best approach here?

Comment: You can use `diff()` to compare two `DateTime` objects or you can use `getTimestamp()` to get the unix timestamp of these `DateTime` objects and compare these.

Comment: Unclear what you're asking, why don't you include the foreach code you mentioned?  Hard to know what type of structure you have your friday dates in.

Comment: to check that day is friday you can do this `$i->format('w') == 5`

Comment: *i have to do foreach loop inside the for loop, but the problem is that it duplicates which is actually the number of row returned on my mysql data result that contain friday date.* Try to share what you have. But not to expect people to be mentalists and guess what do you have and what do you want to get.

Answer (score 0):

You can use date('D') to check day code from regular date format.

```
$begin = new DateTime("2018-06-01");  
$end   = new DateTime("2018-06-30");  

for($i = $begin; $i <= $end; $i->modify('+1 day')){  
    if($i->date('D') == 'Fri'){
     //echo something
    }

}
```

Comment: the friday is just an example, it could change from time to time